# xpath query to a specific number on a page

Tags: xpath, import, google-sheets-query

I couldn't manage to write the correct XPATH code to import a number from the following page into my google sheet cell. I want to use the IMPORTXML function of google sheet.

Any help is highly appreciated in advance.

Source page: https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=USD&to=AED

The number I want to insert into a cell is shown below

[image]

Tried

```
//div[@id='rates_detail_desc']/strong[2]
```

Comment: The number I want to import is shown in red in this photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNJFi.png

Comment: Share your current XPath and output

Comment: @Andersson  The page code I get from chrome inspect section is    `<div 
id="rates_detail_desc" class="detailChart-description"><strong>USD/AED</strong> close:<strong>3.67250</strong> low:<strong>3.67250</strong> high:<strong>3.67250</strong></div>`  and thus I used this xpath code:   `//div[@id='rates_detail_desc']/strong[2]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind helping hand.  @Andersson